# ManyToManyField with extra information

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working on a django website and I need to store some information about the user like a `isVerified` BooleanField and a profile picture in an ImageField as well as ratings which stores ratings a user has given different `elements`. So I made a model like this:

```
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser):
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    current_profile = models.ImageField(default=static('img/default_profile.jpg'))
    ratings     = models.ManyToManyField(Element, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

however I'd like to save some more about these ratings (like a timestamp and the actual value the user rated)

Do I need to make a seperate model just for that or can this be acchieved in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use intermediary table that can be specified via the `through` keyword.

For example:

```python
class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser):
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    current_profile = models.ImageField(default=static('img/default_profile.jpg'))
    ratings = models.ManyToManyField(Element, on_delete=models.CASCADE, through='UserProfileElement')

class UserProfileElement(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('User'))
    element = models.ForeignKey(Element, models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_('Element'))
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(_('Timestamp'), auto_now_add=True)
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Rating'))

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'element')
```

[Django docs: ManyToManyField.through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)